# c# process start it only outputs when the application is closed Problem

Tags: c#, process, console, process.start

iam develop game server launcher when i am start Multi Theft Auto server no write output but when server closed program write output:

```
private static Process p = new Process();
    public static void test()
    {
        try {

            p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\MTA San Andreas 1.5\server\server.exe";
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = "";
            //p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Program Files(x86)\MTA San Andreas 1.5\server\";
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

            p.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(p_ErrorDataReceived);
           p.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args) => Console.WriteLine("received output: {0}", args.Data);

            p.Start();
            p.BeginOutputReadLine();
            p.BeginErrorReadLine();


            var writer = p.StandardInput;


            while (true)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            p.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }


    }
```

İmage:
https://ibb.co/n07P2dT

Comment: It might be caching the output.  Does the writer have a flush method, or something similar, you can call before the while loop?

Comment: my problem is it doesn't output until the program closes –

Answer (score 0):

When to you write to `StreamWriter` it doesn't immediately write to the location, it write to the buffer. You have to `flush` this buffer in order to "write" the location. Meaning either manually call `writer.Flush()` or wrap your code with a `using` block. See [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter?view=net-6.0).

You will most probably have to modify your code to remove infinite loop and add some sort of "*breaking*" mechanism to let the program know when to `flush`. Maybe have a background thread do this.

Comment: my problem is it doesn't output until the program closes